# SQL Server 2008 Full Text Search - indexing is VERY SLOW

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I'm experimenting with full text search.  I have a 50 million row table with an xml field, and set up a full text search on it.  It's 2 days later now, and the indexing is STILL ONGOING.  It looks like it's not completely hung, and is continuing to index, but very, very slowly.   I based this on the fact that when I query the table, i get more results all the time.  Also, looking at the full text index properties (right-click on table in sql server management studio) the Full Text Docs Processed continues to go up

Is this normal, for indxing to be so slow?  At this speed, it's not usable. I see no errors in the full text search log file.  Looking at the log file more carefully - I see that apparently when I created a half million row table and put the full text index on that, it took about 1 hour to index. So, extrapolating from that, it WOULD take about 100 hours to index my table.

How can I speed this up?

thanks for any input!
Sylvia

Comment: What is the problem? I mean, CPU bound? IO bound? wat about discs? Locks? Can we have an analysis of the server state, please.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I should have included more info.  At this point I've found a webpage (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142560.aspx) that appears to have some very detailed information about full text indexing performance with SQL Server 2008, and I'll go through that in detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With 50 million rows, you are reaching a scale where the sql servers have too much other overhead and would be better with an existing text search engine that uses inverted indexes.  There are various flavors of Sharepoint search for very little money, or you could use an open source search engine and move on from there.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I'm still gathering information on what kind of insert rate we will have (the 50 million was just a test) but you make a valid point.